# Ranged based loop to old style for old compilers

Tags: c++, loops, md5, ranged-loops

Recently I was trying to use this code to generate a MD5 from a String.

```
string SecureInfrastructure::Generate_MD5_FromString(const string &data)
{
    unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    MD5((unsigned char*)data.c_str(), data.size(), result);

    std::ostringstream sout;
    sout<<std::hex<<std::setfill('0');
    for(long long c: result)
    {
        sout<<std::setw(2)<<(long long)c;
    }
    return sout.str();
}
```

However, the compiler that I am using does not support range based for loops and I tried to convert this code into the traditional `for(...;...;...)` loop with the code presented below.

```
string SecureInfrastructure::Generate_MD5_FromString(const string &data)
{
    unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    MD5((unsigned char*)data.c_str(), data.size(), result);

    std::ostringstream sout;
    sout<<std::hex<<std::setfill('0');
    for(long long c; c<sizeof(result); c++) // long long c: result
    {
        sout<<std::setw(2)<<(long long)c;
    }
    return sout.str();
}
```

When, I tested it did not work because I am getting an empty string. I am having difficulties in find where the error is. How should I reimplement the first code with the traditional for-loop?

Comment: *I tested it did not work* -- You need to be more specific than just saying "it did not work".

Comment: I edited and explained that I am getting an empty string from the function

Comment: When you debugged your code, how many iterations were done using your rewrite of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have

```
for(long long c: result)
{
    sout<<std::setw(2)<<(long long)c;
}
```

the `for(long long c: result)` says: for each element in `result` assign it to a variable of type `long long` named `c`.  The body of the loop then uses `c`.  To get that same behavior in a regular for loop you need to do the same thing.  To tell the compiler to loop through all the elements you need

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
```

instead of creating a variable you can just use the element directly in the loop.  That would look like

```
sout<<std::setw(2)<<(long long)result[index_of_element];
```

and combining that together you get

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
{
    sout<<std::setw(2)<<(long long)result[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you use `c` uninitialized and start stepping it. That leads to undefined behaviour:

```
for(long long c; c<sizeof(result); c++)
```

This should do it:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
    sout << std::setw(2) << (unsigned) result[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are not initializing c and also you are not referring to the result array nowhere

```
for(long long c = 0; /*Initialize*/ c<sizeof(result); c++) // long long c: result
{
  //use result[c]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH` instead of `sizeof(result)`. And "c" has no initial value of 0 I think.